# Sharepoint Skype status field with skype button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I have a skype name field in a list.
 I would like to use skype button to it or any other way users can can call or chat by pressing on it.
Is this possible?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

A simple, no-code, solution which I've used in the past, is to create a SharePoint calculated column and add the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href='skype:",[SkypeAccountName],"'><img title='Skype Me' src='/path/to/image/skype.png'></a>")
```

where `SkypeAccountName` is your field holding the Skype name.

The trick to render the calulated column as hyperlink is to select the output type to be `number` and not plain text.

A more sophisticated solution would not require a second field, but rather using a JSLink display template with a bunch of JavaScript to create the link.

Here's something which should get you started:

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {'SkypeAccountName': {'View': ViewListRenderMethod,'DisplayForm': DisplayFormFormRenderMethod}};

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function ViewListRenderMethod(ctx) {
    var itemSkypeAccountName = ctx.CurrentItem.SkypeAccountName;
    return '<a title="Skype me" href="skype:' + itemSkypeAccountName + '"><img title="Skype Me" src="/path/to/image/skype.png"></a>';
}
function DisplayFormFormRenderMethod(ctx) {
    var itemSkypeAccountName = ctx.CurrentItem.SkypeAccountName;
    return '<a title="Skype me" href="skype:' + itemSkypeAccountName + '"><img title="Skype Me" src="/path/to/image/skype.png"></a>';
}
```

For more info on how to work with JSLink display templates, just check

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html

or MSDN. There are plenty of examples out in the wild.